# Ruby - Check if string only contains specific charaters and invalidate model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

Is there a way to check if a string contains only illegal characters? These characters are not illegal if anything else is there, but if they are by themselves, they are illegal.

For example:

```
illegal_characters = ['$', '^', '\\']
```

so

```
'$'               # bad
'^^$^$^^\\\\^\\$' # bad
'$oh hey there'   # good
```

Is there a way to check for that?

Comment: by "not illegal if anything else is there", do you just mean a letter `a-zA-Z`?

Comment: '\\' isn't a character, it is a string. So do you want '\\\' to be legal?

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov I was just giving an example. I wanted \ to be illegal, but I imagine I would have to escape it?

Comment: You are correct that you would have to escape it '\\' is correct in this case.

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov `'\\\'` is not even a string, escaping blows the closing quote away. `'\\'`, however, is a single-character string, totally legit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't tag this rails, but you did say invalidate the model... so...

```
validates_format_of :myfield, without: /\A[$^\\]+\z/
```

Note that it's `without`, not `with`.  So you're saying if `myfield` only contains those characters then fail.

If it's not rails, that regex will still do what you want.

Comment: @Jeff It's `validates :my_field format: {without: regex}` with new syntax.

Comment: Awesome. This works great. Is there a way to add a message if need be?

Comment: @Jeff yes just add `message: "YOUR MESSAGE"` to the `Hash` eg. `validates_format_of :myfield, without: /\A[$^\\]+\z/, message: 'Wrong format'`

Answer (score 0):

It is not elegant and maybe someone can offer a better answer but this will work.

```
illegal_strings = ['$', '^', '\\']
valid_string = Proc.new{ |s| !s.chars.all?{ |a| illegal_strings.include?(a) } }
# OR
# valid_string = Proc.new{ |s| !s.gsub(/[$^\\]/,'').empty?}
valid_string.call('$')
#=> false
valid_string.call('^^$^$^^\\\\^\\$')
#=> false
valid_string.call('$oh hey there')
#=> true
```

If this is Rails then Philip's answer is more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
BADDIES = '$^\\'

def all_good?(str)
  str.delete(BADDIES).size > 0
end

all_good? '$'               # false
all_good? '^^$^$^^\\\\^\\$' # false
all_good? '$oh hey there'   # true
all_good? 'oh hey there'    # true
```